# Preferred jQuery plugin for custom easing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see that both jQuery Easing plugin and jquery UI plugin provide custom easing. Is there any difference between the two? Do javascript developers prefer one to another? My gut feeling was that if I only needed easing without any extra functionalities jQuery Easing would be the way to go, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Query Easing Plugin: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: If you look at all the options in [gsgd page's dropdown](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), and compare with the [jQuery UI's easing effects list](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing), you will see that both provide the same custom 31 easing effects (linear is not listed in gsgd and "def"[ault] doesn't work properly there for me, which should be linear). It leads me to assume the same as you, include gsgd's plugin when you need only easing effects without the UI. It's a good question though, I can't find any reference to gsgd being included in the UI effects core or not.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's documentation says:

> The excellent jQuery easing plugin porting Robert Penners advanced easing functions to jQuery has been included into effects.core.js.

Since jQuery UI's core effects plugin (jquery.effects.core.js) is almost three times larger than jQuery easing plugin (jquery.easing.1.3.js), i.e. 23kb vs 7.9kb for uncompressed javascript file, if all one needs is advanced easing, jQuery easing plugin can be a better or at least cleaner choice. jQuery UI's core effects plugin provides color animations and class transitions in addition to advanced easing which account for it's larger file size.